# Java Free Hosting

Tags: java

I'm looking for a free hosting for my Java web page, that uses Servlets and JSP. There is any good one out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how the application is written, you may want to look at [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html). I believe there is some amount of free applications (? 10 ?) you are allowed to run within certain bandwidth parameters.

Converting well behaved JSP/Servlet application to run GAE should not be too difficult - the part that may need bigger change is data persistence.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge, no.  Hosting java applications on a shared server or container gets unrealistic pretty darn fast if "free" hosting is the goal due to both resource utilization and classloading / perm gen memory heap usage.

If you really want to host your java web applications somewhere for cheap, I'd suggest going with http://www.linode.com/ and using their cheapest offering around $20/mo.  They offer full root access so you can install your JVM, servlet container, and other tools of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers note that there is shared Java hosting which is way cheaper than a VPS. The only one I know of off the top of my head is [Godaddy](http://godaddy.com), but there are other options out there